# openssh - Adding an ssh key from putty to authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, putty

I have been provided with an ssh key by a colleague to add to the `authorized_keys` file for an account on a linux server so they can access that account.

The file looks something like this:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20160816"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEApoYJFnGDNis/2oCT6/h9Lzz2y0BVHLv8joXM
s4SYcYUVwBxNzqJsDWbikBn/h32AC36qAW24Bft+suGMtJGS3oSX53qR7ozsXs/D
lCO5FzRxi4JodStiYaz/pPK24WFOb4sLXr758tz2u+ZP2lfDfzn9nLxregZvO9m+
zpToLCWlXrzjZxDesJOcfh/eszU9KUKXfXn6Jsey7ej8TYqB2DgYCfv8jGm+oLVe
UOLEl7fxzjgcDdiLaXbqq7dFoOsHUABBV6kaXyE9LmkbXZB9lQ==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

The man page for `authorized_keys` (well, sshd) makes it clear that the file expects each key to take up a single line.  So I guess I need to convert this key to a single-line format?  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1416315/how-can-i-convert-a-public-key-generated-by-putty-to-rfc-4716-format/1633533#1633533

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is an accepted answer for this question, but I think it's worth noting that there is a way to do this using the `ssh-keygen` tool rather than `sed`:

```
ssh-keygen -i -f ssh2.pub > openssh.pub
```

Where `ssh2.pub` is your existing ssh2 key and openssh.pub will be the key in openssh format. If you just want to copy and paste you can leave out the redirect and use:

```
ssh-keygen -i -f ssh2.pub
```

Answer (score 22):

- Remove the `BEGIN` and `END` lines
- Optionally remove the `Comment` line (you can keep note of this if you want to add it as a comment later)
- Remove all remaining line-breaks
- Add the text "ssh-rsa" to the start of the line

The key now becomes:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEApoYJFnGDNis/2oCT6/h9Lzz2y0BVHLv8joXMs4SYcYUVwBxNzqJsDWbikBn/h32AC36qAW24Bft+suGMtJGS3oSX53qR7ozsXs/DlCO5FzRxi4JodStiYaz/pPK24WFOb4sLXr758tz2u+ZP2lfDfzn9nLxregZvO9m+zpToLCWlXrzjZxDesJOcfh/eszU9KUKXfXn6Jsey7ej8TYqB2DgYCfv8jGm+oLVeUOLEl7fxzjgcDdiLaXbqq7dFoOsHUABBV6kaXyE9LmkbXZB9lQ== rsa-key-20160816
```

This one-liner will do all of the above, apart from append the comment (this assumes GNU `sed`):

```
sed key.pub -e 's/---- B.*/ssh-rsa /;/Comment:/d;'|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g;s/---.*//'
```

Comment: WIll it work for ssh private key as well.?

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

For the example key you provided (output by PuTTY):

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20160816"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEApoYJFnGDNis/2oCT6/h9Lzz2y0BVHLv8joXM
s4SYcYUVwBxNzqJsDWbikBn/h32AC36qAW24Bft+suGMtJGS3oSX53qR7ozsXs/D
lCO5FzRxi4JodStiYaz/pPK24WFOb4sLXr758tz2u+ZP2lfDfzn9nLxregZvO9m+
zpToLCWlXrzjZxDesJOcfh/eszU9KUKXfXn6Jsey7ej8TYqB2DgYCfv8jGm+oLVe
UOLEl7fxzjgcDdiLaXbqq7dFoOsHUABBV6kaXyE9LmkbXZB9lQ==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

The one-line format (eg as expected by `authorized_keys`) is:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEApoYJFnGDNis/2oCT6/h9Lzz2y0BVHLv8joXM
s4SYcYUVwBxNzqJsDWbikBn/h32AC36qAW24Bft+suGMtJGS3oSX53qR7ozsXs/D
lCO5FzRxi4JodStiYaz/pPK24WFOb4sLXr758tz2u+ZP2lfDfzn9nLxregZvO9m+
zpToLCWlXrzjZxDesJOcfh/eszU9KUKXfXn6Jsey7ej8TYqB2DgYCfv8jGm+oLVe
UOLEl7fxzjgcDdiLaXbqq7dFoOsHUABBV6kaXyE9LmkbXZB9lQ==
```

There's no magical command to convert here. If you look close, I just removed a few lines, removed the newlines, and prepended it with `ssh-rsa`

## Explanation

The default format that putty uses is defined in [RFC4716](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4716).

From `man ssh-keygen`, `ssh-keygen` supports 3x formats:

1. RFC4716
2. PKCS8
3. PEM

> ```
>  -m key_format
>         Specify a key format for the -i (import) or -e (export) conver‐
>         sion options.  The supported key formats are: “RFC4716” (RFC
>         4716/SSH2 public or private key), “PKCS8” (PEM PKCS8 public key)
>         or “PEM” (PEM public key).  The default conversion format is
>         “RFC4716”.  Setting a format of “PEM” when generating or updating
>         a supported private key type will cause the key to be stored in
>         the legacy PEM private key format.
> ```

The default used by `ssh-keygen` and PuTTY is actually the same (RFC4716), except that the `id_rsa.pub` file puts it on one line, which is what the `authorized_keys` file expects.

### Example Key

For example, I'll generate a new key in Debian 10:

```
user@disp8452:~$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:lrwmOoBF1PEtDbbVkFwREgWqdJlH5ViEYzQpUAyPyNY user@disp8452
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
| ...+*+oX&Oo     |
| ..o.=o@B*.      |
| .+ E Xo=..      |
| ... o + .       |
| o  .   S        |
|. .    . .       |
|   .  . o        |
|    .. o         |
|    ..           |
+----[SHA256]-----+
user@disp8452:~$ cat /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzU4exWqu4tsgWIJleq1AJ98cGHswD80cphWYOasspBoOPgdv1rljgb9PFAQX19X+rofYi+aYd1glP8BhRC3rt4zE26J54h8tt46DBT1TkFPJ2O3ULhLSqcv9zENGkGB0bfXkvhI0p/tP4b1a0NnvmNME9i6qyo8/7mPLovaKwP1qkd7/a+p1DQr2XoId9U6G4rx0TKsvhbjmDvaCWAm4c5LT3WbQHh301DWiwsN8xn8LkxaO4GtdIqxHOyj7lmQZGw8ixuvoIY/FjgXhSPGmaWLyz2o45TrTNP7vWxWqgcDi2CegziD67+UN4tBZvB9HwR6V3aaCrV59H15ukAtK1 user@disp8452
user@disp8452:~$
```

#### RFC4716

You can get that in the PuTTY RFC4716 format as follows:

```
user@disp8452:~$ ssh-keygen -ef /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -mRFC4716
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "2048-bit RSA, converted by user@disp8452 from OpenSSH"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzU4exWqu4tsgWIJleq1AJ98cGHswD80cphWYOas
spBoOPgdv1rljgb9PFAQX19X+rofYi+aYd1glP8BhRC3rt4zE26J54h8tt46DBT1TkFPJ2
O3ULhLSqcv9zENGkGB0bfXkvhI0p/tP4b1a0NnvmNME9i6qyo8/7mPLovaKwP1qkd7/a+p
1DQr2XoId9U6G4rx0TKsvhbjmDvaCWAm4c5LT3WbQHh301DWiwsN8xn8LkxaO4GtdIqxHO
yj7lmQZGw8ixuvoIY/FjgXhSPGmaWLyz2o45TrTNP7vWxWqgcDi2CegziD67+UN4tBZvB9
HwR6V3aaCrV59H15ukAtK1
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
user@disp8452:~$
```

Note that the fingerprint line is actually the same, so you can manually convert between the multi-line format output by PuTTY and the one-line format just by removing the `BEGIN`, `Comment`, and `END` lines. Then remove newlines and prepend it with `ssh-rsa` .

#### PKCS8

And to be complete, here's the PKCS8 format of the key above:

```
user@disp8452:~$ ssh-keygen -ef /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -mPKCS8
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAs1OHsVqruLbIFiCZXqtQ
CffHBh7MA/NHKYVmDmrLKQaDj4Hb9a5Y4G/TxQEF9fV/q6H2IvmmHdYJT/AYUQt6
7eMxNuieeIfLbeOgwU9U5BTydjt1C4S0qnL/cxDRpBgdG315L4SNKf7T+G9WtDZ7
5jTBPYuqsqPP+5jy6L2isD9apHe/2vqdQ0K9l6CHfVOhuK8dEyrL4W45g72glgJu
HOS091m0B4d9NQ1osLDfMZ/C5MWjuBrXSKsRzso+5ZkGRsPIsbr6CGPxY4F4Ujxp
mli8s9qOOU60zT+71sVqoHA4tgnoM4g+u/lDeLQWbwfR8Eeld2mgq1efR9ebpALS
tQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
user@disp8452:~$
```

#### PEM

And the PEM format:

```
user@disp8452:~$ ssh-keygen -ef /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -mPEM
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAs1OHsVqruLbIFiCZXqtQCffHBh7MA/NHKYVmDmrLKQaDj4Hb9a5Y
4G/TxQEF9fV/q6H2IvmmHdYJT/AYUQt67eMxNuieeIfLbeOgwU9U5BTydjt1C4S0
qnL/cxDRpBgdG315L4SNKf7T+G9WtDZ75jTBPYuqsqPP+5jy6L2isD9apHe/2vqd
Q0K9l6CHfVOhuK8dEyrL4W45g72glgJuHOS091m0B4d9NQ1osLDfMZ/C5MWjuBrX
SKsRzso+5ZkGRsPIsbr6CGPxY4F4Ujxpmli8s9qOOU60zT+71sVqoHA4tgnoM4g+
u/lDeLQWbwfR8Eeld2mgq1efR9ebpALStQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
user@disp8452:~$
```