# How to make in SSH private key from one line, three lines

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, sed, awk, private-key

i have ssh-key, something like this

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- my_super_secret_password -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Of course this key does not work. When i am doing manual things, something, like this

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
my_super_secret_password 
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

It works. When i am deleting this `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and this `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, my ssh-key does not work.

So, the question. How, i can make automatically via some command, like `sed` or `awk`, or any other command, how can i make from this string

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- my_super_secret_password -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

these three strings

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
my_super_secret_password 
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Thanks for your help. If you know any other answer on this question, i am glad to hear you. The reason, why i need it, because i have secret keys storage in `AWS Secret Manager`. So, this manager stores keys only in one line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openssh - Adding an ssh key from putty to authorized\_keys](https://serverfault.com/questions/797044/openssh-adding-an-ssh-key-from-putty-to-authorized-keys)

Answer (score 19):

I would personally base64-encode the key, store it, then base64 decode it when you need it.

Encode:

```
echo "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- my_super_secret_password -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" | openssl base64 | tr -d '\n'
```

Decode:

```
echo "LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLSBteV9zdXBlcl9zZWNyZXRfcGFzc3dvcmQgLS0tLS1FTkQgUlNBIFBSSVZBVEUgS0VZLS0tLS0K" | openssl base64 -A -d
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, quick and hacky.

```
echo "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- my_super_secret_password -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" | sed 's/\(KEY----- \)/\1\n/' | sed 's/\(-----END\)/\n\1/'
```